# Allowed file security for iOS data files, encoding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to provide some protection for my data files. The files will be exported by my app to the cloud. I don't want users to mess around and break the data files.

However, the app store rules don't allow to use encryption.

I'm thinking some sort of encoding.

Can anyone suggest what I might use that would be allowed ?

I've tried using zip files, but the libraries are big and / or out of date and aren't optimized for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App Store rules don't forbid encryption, you need to get the appropriate government permissions and provide these details when you submit your application.

Once you have done this, you should read [Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11).

Comment: I don't want to go to all that effort, just want something reasonable

Comment: Reasonable would be to let users who mangle their documents to expect them to fail to load.  If you have version/device requirements, I suggest you post them in the question.  "Older devices" is too vague.

Comment: Pre iOS4 I mean, I guess. I guess I also want to protect my database setup.

Comment: [iOS 3 and below are effectively dead.](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/08/ios-versions-in-the-wild/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the built-in data protection with iCloud files.

Encryption may need an export license, depending on what you do. (Enabling HTTPS requires it, for example.)

I don't recall zlib being all that big, and I'm sure we included it in an iOS game (since we used libpng).

If you want users to not break things, why not use a checksum?